# Active Directory Administrative Center crashes on Windows 10

Tags: active-directory

I started a new job with a new Windows 10 laptop with up to date patches (not anniversary edition.)  I installed RSAT Tools for 10 (WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu).  I can open it and see my domain but when I double click on a group to see it's properties it crashes with a .NET runtime error.

```
Application: dsac.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(System.Object[])
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.UI.App.Start()
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.UI.Startup.Main()
```

Even if I open the old Active Directory Users and Groups snap-in I double click and only see security settings (not what I expect).  So in the meantime I am just hopping on a server to do admin work :-(

Comment: 2016 rsat ? Try 2012r2 rsat

Comment: @yagmoth555.  I tried that on my Win10 PC and got a message saying that version isn't compatible with my version of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The 2017 January patch bundle removed RSAT as part of the update.  Reinstalled RSAT for Windows 10 (KB2693643) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the instructions on this [TechNet Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b38855a-b9a3-47c0-a7d1-11a5f65102b3/rsat-windows-10-ad-remote-desktop-services-profile-tab?forum=win10itprosetup) to fix a similar issue with ADAC. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but you should quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: The versions on my 2012 server are very old compared to what is currently on my Win10 box...so I did not want to try this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a bug removal windows security updates.
Windows 2012 r2 uninstall kb3205401
Windows 10 uninstall kb3205386

UPD: Released 11/01/2017 KB3210721 update replaces kb3205386, is also not recommended for installer. After you install ADAC receive the error "Active Directory Administrative Center must close due to an unknown error."

Comment: I have neither of the KB's mentioned above on my Win10 machine.